# Can Google App Engine / GWT plugin work with multi-module projects?

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

The getting started tutorial for Google App Engine / GWT describes a very simple application using a single eclipse project (module). I'm porting a JPA / Hibernate based project to GAE and have a service layer module. It all compiles but when I attempt to run as a web-app from eclipse, obviously it doesn't have access to the service layer.

How do I get Eclipse to build a Jar, and include it (with the src) in the GWT project module - i.e. deployed to the WEB-INF/lib directory?

I can't believe that Google are not addressing this and seem to have just skimmed over this gaping hole.

Comment: I usually just symlink the first project's build directory into the second project's WEB-INF/lib. Works fine for me.

Comment: I tried that (via Eclipse) but it didn't seem to work. I could try setting that up using the console I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ant and setup an [Ant Builder](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) that executes when you save your java classes to create the [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)

This should accomplish what you are looking for.